# Parsing particular data from a string in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I want a macro with which I can extract the % number (`31.50` in the below case) and date (`19-Jan-2011`) from a string. Please see the example below.

```
Österreichische Industrieholding AG (OIAG) 94,500,000 31.50% 19-Jan-2011 Other Substantial/Declarable
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: @Vikas-Maheshwary: it is very important that you know very well how that string is composed in order to make an accurate extraction of your data.  Is the Percentage allways having the "%" symbol? could there be anywhere else a "%" symbol? Is Date allways in the 5th position?. Each element is separated by a space or a Tab?
.....

Answer (score 1):

For that example and others where they are delimited by a space how about;

```
Function f(v As String)
    Dim last_percent As Integer, space_before_it As Integer, space_after_it As Integer
    last_percent = InStrRev(v, "%")
    If (last_percent = 0) Then Exit Function
    space_before_it = InStrRev(v, " ", last_percent)
    space_after_it = InStr(last_percent + 1, v, " ")
    Debug.Print Mid$(v, 1 + space_before_it, last_percent - space_before_it)
    Debug.Print Mid$(v, 1 + space_after_it, 11)
End Function
```

Comment: Hi Alex,Thanks for the reply.I still ahve a problem. In the same example, how can i extract date...from the pattern i am seeing date is always after the % symbol and before and after there is always a space. Secondly, if i want to extract the first few words before numeral starts, in this case, Österreichische Industrieholding AG (OIAG), how should i go. If i want to go for a macro, where i can extarct the % (in this case 31.50), date and thirdly the words before numeral starts (in this caseÖsterreichische Industrieholding AG (OIAG)).Can you pls help me with a compiled macro for all the three